# how to create a column for a dynamic openERP field?

Tags: python, odoo, openerp-7, openerp-8

I have been working on dynamic fields for my OpenERP-7 module. My field is not storing the data entered to it . I think for that I will have to create a column for it . So that it will start storing the records. But I dont have any idea to create a column for a dynamic field. I need some expert's advice here.

Thanks

Comment: what type of data will be stored? can you give some examples? :-)

Comment: any data like int,string

Answer (score 1):

ya as per my knowledge you can create  dynamic field for hr.employee object

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<openerp>
<data>
<record id="view_employee_form" model="ir.ui.view">
<field name="name">hr.employee.form</field>
<field name="model">hr.employee</field>
<field name="inherit_id" ref="hr.view_employee_form"/>
<field name="arch" type="xml">
<!-- Field can be  added after the marital field state as married -->
<xpath expr="//field[@name='marital']" position="after">
<field name="marriage_date" attrs="{'invisible':[('marital','in',[False, 'single','widower','divorced'])]}"/>
</xpath>
</field>
</record>
</data>
</openerp>
```